# fxml - Hidden control still keeps a place in ToolBar

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am working on this notepad that implements a spellchecker in FXML. I wanted to use a loader while the spellchecker works in the background so I used a `ProgressIndicator`. The problem is that when I hide the `ProgressIndicator`, it still keeps a little space where it was originally.

[image]

What I want is to hide the control along with the space that it holds just like it doesn't exist.

Here's my FXML code:

```
<ToolBar onKeyTyped="#onTextChanged" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <items>
        <Button fx:id="btnCorrect" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onCorrectionClicked" >
           <graphic>
              <ImageView fx:id="imgButton" fitHeight="23.0" fitWidth="23.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                 <image>
                    <Image url="@../../img/book.png" />
                 </image>
              </ImageView>
           </graphic>    
        </Button>
        <ProgressIndicator  prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="23.0" />
        <Separator orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="3.0" />
        ...
     </items>
  </ToolBar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing

```
progressIndicator.setVisible(false)
```

Write

```
toolbar.getItems().remove(progressIndicator);
```

You can re-add it writing `toolbar.getItems().add(1,progressIndicator);`

Comment: It's unnecessary to check, if the list contains an element before removing it, at least if the list satisfies the contract of [`List.remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: It depends on your coding. `List.remove` might throw an exception the second time if it is read twice.

Comment: But that only happens, if `List.remove` is implemented the wrong way. `List.remove` javadoc second sentence: *"If this list does not contain the element, it is unchanged."*

Comment: Okay.. got it.. I thought it might give error as the element is not present. I'll edit my answer. Thanks for clearing it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can free up layout spaces if you detach the nodes via the [managed](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#managedProperty) Property - this will force the parent to re-draw without your node since it is not under its control anymore. Dont forget to re-attach it with the same property otherwise it will never show again